# What does LOB refer to in "maximum size of LOB"?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I have setup an AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance. I have a table `A` which has around `2TB` of data.

Table `A` doesn't have any `unique` or `primary key`. We can't have `unique` column on `A` because nothing is `unique`.
It has a `tags` column which is `text[] or _text` which has *not null constraint*

I am migrating the data from source `S` to target `T`. I went with `Full LOB mode`, but I got below errors,

> Source must have primary key or unique index

also,

> null value is not allowed on column tags

Then I went with `limited LOB mode` with max value of `100MB` and it succeeded. But now I am concerned about the data loss,

> LOBs that exceed the maximum LOB size are truncated

I just want to confirm what AWS is referring as ***maximum size of LOBs***?

- Is it the tags data size (toast size) for individual row?
- OR is it the value of whole tags column?
- Why does I get error in Full LOB mode but not in limited?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.LOBSupport.html

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dms-improve-speed-lob-data#

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dms-error-null-value-column

Comment: _"Table A doesn't have any unique or primary key"_ - **argh!** - fix that first! If your source data is non-unique then add a `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` column: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Comment: @Dai That I only get in Full LOB mode. I am thinking of going with limited lob mode. In that case, I don't need unique index or primary key, right?

Comment: Youre data are a mess. Add an artificial primary key.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I agree with you all. Data is a mess! But why I am having error in Full LOB mode and not in Limited LOB mode?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Amazon's tools.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it the tags data size (toast size) for individual row?

Individual row.

> Why do I get error in Full LOB mode but not in limited?

In Full LOB mode, it needs to perform a lookup.

First, it will migrate the non-LOB columns, and then it migrates LOB columns by performing a lookup using the primary key (PK) or unique key (UK).

1. https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dms-improve-speed-lob-data